# run programs with an argument?

Tags: java

How does one go about making programs that accept added arguments at command line?

such as the program printMe.java

if i ran it like

```
java printMe im so cool
```

it would print, "im so cool"

Im looking to figure out how i can pass extra information to my program through command line arguments!

Comment: This is a very general question with many resources available with a Google of `java command line arguments` or something similar. Perhaps you have a more specific question?

Comment: @Mr. Schiadance: general questions are not generally a bad thing, especially if they have a definite answer. If you could link to a question which this one duplicates, then it would be a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java programs can take arguments.

Simple look at the `String[]` that gets passed in as the argument to your `main` method: it contains the command line arguments!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) // note "args"
```

Java uses that String array to represent command-line arguments to the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PrintMe {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length > 0){
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

```
$ javac PrintMe.java
$ java PrintMe "I'm so cool"
I'm so cool
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the String[] args that is passed into the main function.  This gets filled up with all of the specified parameters.

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java main method has a parameter `String[] args` which will contain any command line arguments passed.

So, in your case, the PrintMe class's main method would look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String s : args) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: typo! `foreach` should be `for`

Comment: @John, @Joachim Sauer - Thanks, was in a rush :)